My Visual Studio Custom Modern Debugger Visualizer can't attach my custom class in Resources.xaml
I want to write custom Visual Studio 2022 Debugger Visualizer. And i have a problem.
There are two Visual Studio debugger visualizers type. One which use DialogDebuggerVisualizer and modern which use DebuggerVisualizerProvider. at the beginning, I wrote a first type of visualizer. And it was cool!. It work's, but have one problem - this type of visualizers don't allow to create non modal windows (((
Then i started to write second type of visualizers ( modern, which use DebuggerVisualizerProvider and RemoteUserControl classes). And this was good, and i create non modal window, it works. Then i created custom type MyString, like this:
public class MyString
 {
 public int a = 0;
 public int b { get; set; } = 1;
 public MyString()
 {
     
 }
 public MyString(string str)
 {
     
 }
}

And XAML resources.xaml file:
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
xmlns:lc="clr-namespace:VSModernExtensionWithWebView2;assembly=VSModernExtensionWithWebView2"
xmlns:my="clr-namespace:AnotherAssembly;assembly=AnotherAssembly">
<system:String x:Key="removeButtonText">Remove</system:String>
<system:String x:Key="addButtonText">Add color</system:String>
<my:MyString x:Key="qeweqwe"></my:MyString>


And here is problem - when i run project , another Visual Studio is opened, and i have an error
[the problem][1]
Exception of type System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException was thrown:
Could not load type 'System.Object' from assembly 'System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0 ...
Please help! What i do wrong? Why this error happens?
And when i remove this line:
    <my:MyString x:Key="qeweqwe"></my:MyString>

Everything works fine. Look's like Visual Studio Extension don't allow to add custom type's into RemoteUserControl XAMl...
Sorry for my english...

The document says,"the XAML can't reference types and assemblies from the extension but can reference types and assemblies from the Visual Studio process."
